# Recovering damaged ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

Situation: One day my SSD hard failed and deleted many files randomly, consisting some files of the OS. Damage was big enough that made the OS unable to boot and even unable to chrooted.

Fortunately I had another Ubuntu on another disc and I was able to recover `chroot` and then boot and network functionality of damaged OS. Then I booted the damaged OS and ran a script that reinstalled every package installed on it (with `apt-get install <package> --reinstall`) it wasn't as easy as I'm describing it, there were lots of packages that needed specific attention.

After that almost everything's fine except running 32bit binaries like wine and adb.
I need an expert in this field to tell me what should I do to recover executing 32bit binaries.

For example suppose that I wanna run wine:
First lets run it on `fish`:

```
# wine
Failed to execute process '/usr/bin/wine'. Reason:
The file '/usr/bin/wine' does not exist or could not be executed.
```

Now lets run it on `bash`:

```
# wine
bash: /usr/bin/wine: No such file or directory
```

Lets enter the full location:

```
# whereis wine
wine: /usr/bin/wine /usr/bin/X11/wine /usr/share/wine /usr/share/man/man1/wine.1.gz
# /usr/bin/wine
bash: /usr/bin/wine: No such file or directory
```

Lets see if the file really exists:

```
# ls -l /usr/bin/wine
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9748 Dec 18 05:11 /usr/bin/wine
```

What `ldd` and `file` say:

```
# ldd /usr/bin/wine
    not a dynamic executable
# file /usr/bin/wine
/usr/bin/wine: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xe4e2fb58bdbbbc2dedf7483825900ed35a6dc989, stripped
```

How to solve this?

Damaged OS is Ubuntu 13.10 amd64.

Comment: when you do `apt-get --reinstall` for 32bit binaries, what happens? What do you mean by "except running 32bit binaries like wine and adb"? Technically, they should be no different than the usual 64bit binaries as far as this situation is concerned. Can you elaborate more on the quoted words please.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the 32bit libs using `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`
or `sudo apt-get ia32-libs --reinstall`

Comment: `apt-get --reinstall` works and doesn't report any problem. The problem is that I can't "run" wine nor adb nor scrivener nor some other 32-bit binaries. When I try to rum them in bash it says: `Failed to execute process '/usr/bin/wine'. Reason: The file '/usr/bin/wine' does not exist or could not be executed.` But the file is there and it's executable. When I try to `ldd` it, `ldd` says: `not a dynamic executable` @Braiam @bkd.online

Comment: Done so @Braiam

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` @Rinzwind

Comment: Any useful messages in dmesg / syslog when you try to run the wine binary? And, have you done a full fsck to make sure the filesystem is consistent?

Comment: Nothing was written to syslog when I ran wine, fsck reported no error.

Comment: Looks like it's something pretty fundamental to do with the handling of the executable format. Have you replaced the kernel with a custom-built one for any reason? Have you tried reinstalling the kernel???

Comment: Other things that spring to mind .. check /etc/ld.so.conf.d/* against another system of the same arch to make sure nothing is missing / corrupted. And rebuild /etc/ld.so.cache using ldconfig, just in case..

Comment: No the kernel is from ubuntu repository. Had tried ldconfig, how should I check /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*

Comment: Compare it with a working system on the same arch, I guess.. My 64bit trusty install has the following files, md5sums shown:

f9f2331782e9078d5472c77e1d9cd869  /vol/trusty/etc/ld.so.conf.d/fakeroot-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf

d4d833fd095fb7b90e1bb4a547f16de6  /vol/trusty/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf

593ad12389ab2b6f952e7ede67b8fbbf  /vol/trusty/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf

Comment: run `debsums -sa` and post the results.

Comment: here it is: https://gist.github.com/sassanh/8746041

Answer (score 1):

The `ldd` results are expected, since the "binary" is just an script:

```
$ file /usr/bin/wine
/usr/bin/wine: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
$ head /usr/bin/wine 
#!/bin/sh

set -e

wine=/usr/bin/wine32
if test "$(file -b -L "$1" | cut -d\  -f1)" = "PE32+" -o "$WINEARCH" = "win64"; then
    wine=/usr/bin/wine64
fi

if test -f $wine; then
```

So, what's the solution? Remove them completely and install them. We don't really know how much damage is there so removing and reinstalling is the most safest:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge wine
```

The same with any package that doesn't work. You can verify the package that correspond to the binary using `dpkg -S`:

```
➜  ~  dpkg -S /usr/bin/wine
wine: /usr/bin/wine
```

Comment: For me it wasn't a script, it was an ELF32 binary, maybe because I'm using `wine1.6-i386`, anyway I purged it and am reinstalling it though I think I've already did so. Lets see what happens.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem. Everything's still the same and file is still binary not a script.

Comment: @Sassan are you using a PPA?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu saucy main` for wine.

Comment: @Sassan there's your problem. Remove the ppa and install Ubuntu packages instead.

Comment: No it's not my problem, the ppa is official wine ppa: `https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa` I will test if the Ubuntu package works, but my problem isn't just about wine, I want to be able to run 32bit binaries others use, I need to use adb from Google's sdk for Android development. There are other applications too. So my problem is running 32bit binaries others use, `ldd` working as expected and things like that.

Comment: @Sassan could you run wine without root?

Comment: Done. Same thing happens when I run it with a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo apt-get install libopenal1:i386
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libopenal1:i386
```

At least this should make `ldd` behave well. I don't know if this will solve the other problems, it might. If not then I would just look at the `ldd` output, and install/reinstall the packages which contains those libraries.

---

Comment: It is already installed, reinstalled it and `ldd` still works the same.

Comment: @Sassan I updates my answer. Maybe that will work.

Comment: After doing so install libc6 failed, my Ubuntu stopped working so I rebooted my machine. Though I was unable to chroot it I copied some libraries and was able to boot it. Now I don't have my mouse pointer which makes things really bad. When I try to reinstall libc it says: dpkg: error processing <address of package> (--unpack): subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1\n No apport written because MaxReports is reached already\n...

Comment: @Sassan Oh fok. I'm so sorry. I didn't thought that installing an i386 package will break your 64 bit system. The `bash: /usr/bin/wine: No such file or directory` message means that one or more 32 bit libraries which are linked to the executable are missing. (The no such file or directors is referring to this missing shared library.) The `ldd` not working I thought means that one of the libopenal1:i386 dependency is missing/broken. I have no clue what did that 32 bit library broke in a 64 bit system. *I would downvote my answer If I could.* :(( I remove those lines, so no anyone else runs it.

Comment: @Sassan Though I don't know that this problem is might be related to your original problem which caused your previous system crash which you were repairing now.

Comment: Any idea what can I do to have my mouse pointer and/or sound output back?

Comment: @Sassan I would just download [the .deb file of the libc:i386 package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/i386/libc6/download) (or with `wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc6_2.17-93ubuntu4_i386.deb`),extarct it and try manually to put every file in it to the correct install place and test if it helps. If its not we would have to check the install scripts in that .deb file too.

Comment: @Sassan I think I see the big mistake I made. I wrote in the install line: `libc6:i386` instead of `libc6-i386`. [Here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/amd64/libc6-i386/filelist) is the files in the correct `libc6-i386` package and [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/i386/libc6/filelist) are the incorrect `libc6:i386` ones. Those packages overlap in the `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` file. So I would first try to put the correct file there.

Comment: @Sassan Also. When you run that command what I gave to you, did the `apt` show that some packages will be removed after the operation? Or it installed the packages without prompting for confirmation? [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74387/is-i386-multiarch-support-broken-on-amd64-debian-sid) suggests some very broken thing in the packaging system and I made you to run that command. Don't know if that is applicable to Ubuntu too, or only Debian.

Comment: I tried to remove libc:i386 by myself, it asked if it's ok to remove some other packages and I replied yes, then rebooted my machine and it didn't boot because was unable to to find my disc. Probably at least one the packages that I uninstalled took part in detecting my disc. Now I'm on another ubuntu machine on an external hard disc and am able to chroot to the damaged one. My plan is to find out the difference between current installed packages and the ones that were installed two days ago (it is stored in /var/backups).

Comment: If I can get back to where I was two days ago then I would go for putting files of libc6-i386 in place. Will inform you about the results.

Comment: @Sassan I hope you manage to get back to at least that point where you were before you run my commands. Looking more into this problem even the installing of that `:i386` package shouldn't normally cause such problems. (at least without clearly prompting that something bad will happen if you run that.) I just don't understand what happened. Regarding that *unable to find the disc* problem. I only saw such messages from GRUB.

Comment: No it's post-grub, I can't recall but it was something like busybox or initshell, it gave me a shell (ash) with restricted commands on a temporary filesystem (that wasn't my disc). But you don't have to blame yourself, libc:i386 couldn't made the damage to a normal distro and I think I can get back to that point. Then we'll see what we can do to make it run 32bit binaries.

Comment: I gave up, installed a new fresh `saucy` and imported configs from old one. The old one was dead. Thank you very much anyway :)

Comment: @Sassan Yes, that was likely a much easier way. I guess the reinstall solved the 32 bit problem too, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/rescatuxdownloads/rescatux-stable/) for repairing your broken machine.
You can make it to bootable usb using [Unetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/?source=recommended).
Hope this could solve your issue.

Comment: It seems to be good tool for issues like grub failures and fs problems, but as I mentioned in the question I solved these issues. My problem was about repairing broken libraries and I gave up (I don't have the damage ubuntu anymore), thanks anyway.